# Laravel HasManyThrough relationship causing memory leaks on creation

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app I created a polls system where users can vote, I achieved this with hasManyThrough relationship.

When I create one or multiple polls (from seeder or public method) I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laraapp.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 350
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laraapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 203
```

I even changed PHP memory_limit to 1024 and 2048, still getting the error.

Poll model relationships:

```
public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Option');
    }

    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Vote', 'App\Models\Option');
    }
```

Polls migration:

```
Schema::create('polls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('question');
            $table->integer('isActive');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Option Model:

```
public function poll()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Poll');
    }

    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Vote');
    }
```

Options migration:

```
Schema::create('options', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table-> unsignedBigInteger('poll_id')->index()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('poll_id')->references('id')->on('polls')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade')->nullable();
            $table->string('text');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Vote model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function option()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Option');
    }
```

Votes migration:

```
Schema::create('votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table-> unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade')->nullable();
            $table-> unsignedBigInteger('option_id')->index()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('option_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade')->nullable();
            $table->unique(['user_id', 'option_id']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And then when I want to create a poll with my seeder (memory error comes even when I create a SINGLE row):

Right now my json file looks like this:

````
[
    { "isActive" : 1, "question" : "¿Qué es lo más importante para ti en una primera cita?",  "optionOne" : "Una buena conversación", "optionTwo" : "Atracción física", "optionThree" : "Sentido del humor","optionFour" : "Intereses comunes"  }
]
```
PollsSeeder
```
$json = File::get(base_path() . '/json/Polls.json');
$polls = json_decode($json, true);

Log::info('Decoded JSON:', $polls);

foreach ($polls as $key => $data) 
            {

                $poll = Poll::create([
                    'question' => $data['question'],
                    'isActive' => $data['isActive'],
                ]);

                if($data['optionOne'] != '')
                {
                    Option::create([
                        'poll_id' => $poll->id,
                        'text' => $data['optionOne'],
                    ]);
                }

                if($data['optionTwo'] != '')
                {
                    Option::create([
                        'poll_id' => $poll->id,
                        'text' => $data['optionOne'],
                    ]);
                }

                if($data['optionThree'] != '')
                {
                    Option::create([
                        'poll_id' => $poll->id,
                        'text' => $data['optionOne'],
                    ]);
                }

                if($data['optionFour'] != '')
                {
                    Option::create([
                        'poll_id' => $poll->id,
                        'text' => $data['optionOne'],
                    ]);
                }
        
            }
```
````

Comment: Add some logging to see if you can track it down. You're logging the json at the beginning, does that show in the log? Add a log line after each create to see where it stops.

Comment: 24M used, Laravel 10.39.0, PHP 8.3.1, no problems with your code when running the seed.